# How would I go about making a facebook info-scraper in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, scripting

I'm building a forum for my friends to use, but since we have been using Facebook's Group feature, the migration will be rough on our forum's "history". So I'm planning to archive all of our old posts.

How would I go about doing this? If it helps, the forum I'm building is written in Rails 3, and perhaps I might want the info to be stored in a text file this way:

```
 name: John Doe
 content: Today I went on a walk with my friends.
 image: http://upload.com/walk.png
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you'd insist on using javascript, delve into the [DOM](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/default.asp) to parse the pages and the [AJAX](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/default.asp) tutorials to learn that and then write something that starts from a given url, fetches the page using an ajax call, loads in the result so you can use the DOM to extract the wanted data and then either pass that data back to a server-side storage function or simply output it.